# "File in use" error while publishing JAR on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, filesystems, publishing

I am publishing a JAR directly into a folder that SmartfoxServer uses for extensions. If the extension is not in use, it works, but if the extension is in use I get a `file in use` error.

Here's the kicker: there is a setting in SmartfoxServer to automatically update the extension during runtime if the file is updated. The point is, that the file *can* be overwriten without negative consequence.

I don't think this is a problem specific to SmartFoxServer or IntelliJ though the solution may be. When I drag and drop the file from a different publish location to the "extensions" directory where I want it, after a confirm overwrite, all is good.

Any recommendations on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the move the installation of the destination directory outside "Program Files". In my case I installed SmartFoxServer at c:\SmartFoxServer_2X instead of inside the Program Files directory.